# Regex to match N-NN-NN

Tags: regex

I need some help with a RegEx pattern match.

How do i write a regex if i want it to match

```
N-NN-N-NN-NN-N-NNN
```

but also

```
N-NN-NN-NN
```

Exmaple:

> 10pcs- ratchet spanner combination wrench **6-8-10-11-12-13-14-15-17-19** 
>   Cr-v,heated  12pcs-1/4dr **4-4.5-5-5.5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13**  Cr-v,heated 
>   17pcs-1/2dr **10-11-12-13-14-15-16-17-18-19-20-21-22-23-24-27-30** 
>   Cr-v,heated **1-2-33** Cr-V heater **1-.2-1-4**

It needs to match where they is at least 2 `-` in the total string. So a phone number like this 020-11223344 is **not** to be matched.

The strings almost always look like this `6-8-10-11-12-13-14-15-17-19` , except sometimes a `.` can apper before a number, they also differ in length, is it possible?

I came up with this so far but it also matches on phone numbers and when a `.` appears it doenst match at all.

```
(\d-[^>])
```

On this page you can find the different patters: http://www.cazoom.nl/en/partij-aanbod/186-pcs-working-tools-trolly-3

Comment: What are your requirements here? Your write up is a little confusing.

Comment: Sorry, tried to make it a bit more clear what the requierments are.

Comment: Highlight what do you want to match from your sample string.

Comment: I made the match bold in the sample string.

Comment: Yes!!! 100% Exactly what i need. Post it as answer!

Comment: @KayNelson I missed one point, just a sec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this pattern:

```
[\d.]+(?:-[\d.]+){2,}
```

Match `[\d.]+` if followed by at least 2x `-[\d.]+`

`(?:` Using a non capturing group for repetition.

[test at regex101](http://regex101.com/r/iX3vO8)

Answer (score 2):

The following regex will match the thing.

```
(?:\.?\d\.?\d?-){2,}\.?\d\.?\d?
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://debuggex.com/r/ev6b7tIj2AW7SfJ_)

Comment: Yeah works great! thanks for your help! Now it also takes the .

Comment: Also upped this, sorry didn't read your comment before, feel free to switch best answer @KayNelson :)

Comment: @Jonny5 doesn't matter :)

Comment: Both answers are great! Will favour Jonny the correct answer as it was a little bit faster! Thanks again guys!

Answer (score 0):

Just try with following regex:

```
^\d-\d{2}-\d(\d-\d{2})|(\d-\d{2}-\d-\d{3})$
```